# What's the quivalent of node_access()?

Tags: nodes, authentication-authorization

I need to test if a given user (in my case, the currently logged-in user) has access to a given node for one of the existing operations.

In Drupal 7, I could use the following code.

```php
if (node_access('view', $node, $account)) {
  // User is allowed to see the node.
}
```

What is the equivalent code for Drupal 8?

I will be running this code from inside a _custom_access check for a specific route I am setting for my custom module.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [Node::access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3Aaccess/8.2.x):

```
if ($node->access('view', \Drupal::currentUser())) {
  // User is allowed to view the node.
}
```